# Why 上 is being used in these cases? How do I read it?

Tags: meaning, readings, suffixes

> 弁護士の小倉秀夫は、**掲示板上**で投稿が殺到することをフレーミング・炎上、**ブログ上**でコメントが殺到することをコメントスクラムと2つに分類している

I wanted to know why 上 need to be used in these cases.

Couldn't it be just 掲示板 and ブログ?

And I also wanted to know if the reading is really じょう.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obvious that they stand for locative case instead of instrumental even without 上{じょう} here. In that sense, it's not necessary. But 上 makes it clear that it's locative. In addition, it tends to be used when the location is virtual one like newspaper or internet, and you are not only a reader but a speaker.